# Passing local variable to partial inside for each loop rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, partials

This is my code for rendering the partial (the @parties collection is being generated correctly, I have tested that):

```
        <% @parties.each do |party| %>
            <div class="item">
              <%= render 'parties/party', :object => party  %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
```

And this is the code in the partial:

```
<%= party.name %>
```

However, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm at my wits end, someone please help :-|

Also, this is the code for the controller to render the view containing the partial (The controller's called default_controller):

```
def index
    @parties = Party.all
end
```

Is it of any consequence that this isn't the parties_controller?

Comment: If you are here for Rails 5, here is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47264342/render-partials-inside-loop-in-rails-5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've tried something like below and it worked

```
<%= render :partial => 'party', :object => party  %>
```

and I can access like `party.name`. the local variable is named after the partial name which is `party` here.

***Note:*** Im assuming that your both partials are of `parties_controller`. So this should work.

***Update:***
Here is what ive tried with again

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    #... ...
    def index
        @posts = Post.all
        @comments = Comment.all #<---- Loading comments from PostsController
        #... ...
    end  
end
```

---

```
#views/posts/index.html.erb

<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= render :partial=>"comments/comment", :object=>comment %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
#views/comments/_comment.html.erb

<%= comment.body %>
```

---

And its working :)

Comment: Though the link http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render is deprecated, it provides some good examples of render.

Comment: The page which uses the partial is not rendered throught the parties_controller - why is that a problem? (The code for the controller being used still gets all parties from the database using @parties = Party.all)

Comment: Ive updated my post with another example. Here is the tiny rails project that im giving example from. **http://goo.gl/bB9Ky**. You can download and can see in action yourself :)

Comment: I literally didn't change a single line of code, just restarted my computer and now it works - christ. Thank you very much for taking the time to help anyway :-) (your solution is exactly what I was doing)

Comment: oh thats great :) may be it required a rails server restart.